# Ruby - factorial / combinations using inject

Tags: ruby, math, combinations, factorial

I am trying to solve this combination (nCr) problem, which essentially boils down to factorials. Any help explaining why my approach doesnt work is helpful..

```
combination = -> (n) do
    -> (r) do

    #This equation I wrote, and it doesnt work, which 
    #This seems like my equation is (n!/r!)*(n-r)!  <-- factorial equation       
    ((1..n).inject(:*)/(1..r).inject(:*)) * (1..(n - r)).inject(:*)

    # This is the answer, which seems like n!/(r!*(n-r)!)    
    #(1..n).inject(1, :*) / (((1..r).inject(1, :*)) * ((1..(n-r)).inject(1, :*)))
    end
end

n = 4
r = 2
nCr = combination.(n)
puts nCr.(r)
```

Comment: `(n choose r) = n!/(r!*(n - r)!)` so I think the formula in the comment is correct, and not the one that's implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple problems:

1. You're using the wrong equation for `C(n,r)`.
2. You're ignoring a couple boundary conditions in your factorial and `C(n,r)` implementations.

The correct formula for the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) is:

```
             n!
C(n,r) = ----------
         r!(n - r)!
```

On to the boundary conditions.

By definition, `0!` is `1` so you should wrap your `inject`s in another lambda:

```
factorial = ->(n) { n == 0 ? 1 : (1..n).inject(:*) }
```

Also, `C(n,r)` is zero if `n < r` so you should check for that.

```
combinations = ->(n, r) do
  if(n < r)
    0
  else
    factorial[n] / (factorial[r] * factorial[n - r])
  end
end
```

You could also short circuit the `n == r` and `r == 0` cases and not worry about `0!`:

```
factorial = ->(n) { (1..n).inject(:*) }
combinations = ->(n, r) do
  if(n < r)
    0
  elsif(n == r || r == 0)
    1
  else
    factorial[n] / (factorial[r] * factorial[n - r])
  end
end
```

Since you're explicitly dealing with combinations you can probably safely ignore the `n < 0` and `r < 0` cases but you can add checks for those as well.

Comment: You could also pass the `initial` value to `inject` to handle `0!`: `(1..0).inject(1, :*) # => 1`...the `initial` defaults to the first element of the collection, but since multiplying by 1 doesn't affect the result, the only difference this makes is when `n < 1`, which causes `(1..n)` to be an empty collection. `inject` will then return the explicit `initial` you pass in. This will change (probably errornous) inputs: `(1..-10).inject(1, :*) # => 1 instead of nil`, but I believe both `n >= r => 0` is supposed to be true for this equation

Comment: @SimpleLime True but I like the explicit `n==0` check, the intent seems more obvious to me. This factorial implementation is only for a limited domain anyway and the `n >= r` cases are better handled elsewhere. You could also put the `factorial` definition inside `combinations` to make it really clear that it is only defined as a notational convenience rather than a general purpose implementation.